# call a function in context of a property

Tags: python, properties

I want to do something like "calling a method of a property":

```
class my_property(property):
    def __init__(self, ...):
       ...
    def some_method(self):
        # do something fancy like a plausibility check, publishing
        # etc. in context of the property.
```

This `improved` property would now be used like a normal property except I can call an extra method:

```
setattr(self.__class__, 'some_value', property(getter, setter))
self.some_value = 5
self.some_value.some_method()
```

Of course this won't work because `some_method()` would be called on what the property returned - which is `5` in my case.

Same for this approach:

```
some_function(self.some_value)
```

What I could do now is s.th. like this:

```
some_function(self, "some_value")
```

But this is bad because this way tools like `pylint` cannot help me any more which is important for me (e.g. check whether `self` has an attribute `some_value`).

Is there a way to use the expression `self.some_value` without writing it in parenthesis and without just evaluating the property?

**My approaches**:

- Don't use properties. Use getters and setters instead.

  ```
  self.some_value.set(5)
  x = self.some_value.get()
  self.some_value.publish()
  ```
- Use unintuitive black magic

  ```
  self.some_value = 5        # will assign a value using `__set__()`
  x = self.some_value        # will read a value using `__get__()`
  self.some_value = publish  # calls `__set__()` with a well known magic value
  ```

  `publish` would be some object known to `__set__` which would make `__set__` accomplish some task.
- Use even darker magic

  ```
  self.some_value = 5           # will assign a value using `__set__()`
  x = self.some_value           # will read a value using `__get__()`
  some_method(self.some_value)  # checks whether `__set__()` has been called from some_method()
  ```

  This can by done by examining the *callstack* inside `__get()__` and check whether `some_method()` is the next element. Instead of returning a value it would produce the desired behavior.

**Background:**

I have implemented some sort of *property tree* which makes use of properties to implement complex get/get semantics. It can be used like this:

```
root.some.subtree.element = 5
```

`element` is a `property`-attribute of `root.some.subtree`. This assignment would call it's `__set__` method which e.g. might store the value on disc or send it through TCP.

In the same way

```
print(root.some.subtree.element)
```

might read and return some value from any provider.

Propertyies have a *set* and a *get* semantic but now I need a **new** semantic, e.g. *publish*. So what I would best like to have would be a `property` implementation with a new `__publish__()` method.

Of course I can easily read the property value and call a function like this:

```
publish_value('root.some.subtree.element', root.some.subtree.element)
```

But in this case `pylint` can't warn me if I misspelled the string expression.

**Edit:**
Originally I wrote

```
self.some_value = property(...)
```

to apply a property to `self`. This doesn't work this way so I corrected it. My intention is to let any object (in my case `self`) have a `property` which I can define extra operations on.

Comment: What is `self` in your examples? If it's an instance of a class you wrote, you can define the magic method `__setattr__` on that class. In `__setattr__`, check what the value currently assigned to the name is. If it's an instance of `my_property`, then maybe redirect that assignment to that `my_property` instance instead. In this way, `self.some_value` still points at `my_property` even after you assign `5` to it. But what you want to do is evil, dark, dynamic magic. No code checker will ever be able to help you with it, but it should work.

Comment: I made a mistake in my post - see the changes. I hope this helps.